# LD_PRELOAD - shell expansion trouble

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to call an executable with LD_PRELOAD-ing some .so files.
But I have a problem, that bash shell expansion seems not to work in variable expansion:

These are the files, I'm trying to set for LD_PRELOAD:

```
nuclear@Korhal:~$ ls speedhack/speedhack*.so
speedhack/speedhack32.so  speedhack/speedhack.so
```

But the shell expansion does not work here:

```
nuclear@Korhal:~$ LD_PRELOAD="speedhack/speedhack*.so" ./my_executable
ERROR: ld.so: object 'speedhack/speedhack*.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

I wrote a script to check, what happens with shell variables expansion:

```
nuclear@Korhal:~$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "LD_PRELOAD w/o quotes:"
echo $LD_PRELOAD

echo "LD_PRELOAD with quotes:"
echo "$LD_PRELOAD"
```

Running it:

```
nuclear@Korhal:~$ LD_PRELOAD="speedhack/speedhack*.so" ./test.sh
ERROR: ld.so: object 'speedhack/speedhack*.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
LD_PRELOAD w/o quotes:
speedhack/speedhack32.so speedhack/speedhack.so
LD_PRELOAD with quotes:
speedhack/speedhack*.so
```

But it gets more complicated: the star is not expanded when variable is accessed from ld.so
and inside the script it gets expanded only if I have no quotes in echo.. As I know, double quotes make no difference in variable expansion (echo $VAR should be the same as echo "$VAR". But echo '$VAR' will print the string $VAR)

The main question: How to force shell expansion in variable assignment, so that LD_PRELOAD holds the list of files?

Comment: Your assumption that quotes don't matter is entirely wrong, and your observation of the actual behavior with and without double quotes illustrates exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the filenames in an array and use that to expand the list:

```
FILES=(speedhack/speedhack*.so)
LD_PRELOAD="${FILES[@]}" ./my_executable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use backquotes or $() syntax to copy-paste the results of a command onto a command-line. Then use double quotes to grab all the words into the same variable.

```
LD_PRELOAD="$(ls speedhack/speedhack*.so)" ./my_executable
```